# Unable to fetch record with least timestamp using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

In my `mongo` database > `sessions` collection, every record has a `fb_id` and `ts` (timestamp). I want to fetch the least timestamp for a particular fb_id. The following query worked successfully in mongoDB shell:

```
db.sessions.find({fb_id: "88877"},{fb_id: 1,ts: 1}).sort({ts:-1}).limit(1) // works perfectly
```

I need this functionality in my PHP script, so I wrote following line of code:

```
echo $tracking->sessions->find(array("fb_id"=> $document["fb_id"]),array("ts"=>1))->sort(array("ts"=>-1))->limit(1)
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class MongoCursor could not be converted to string
```

What is the correct way to fetch this data?

Comment: You are trying to echo out the MongoCursor class, that is returned from find(), don;t do it.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the correct way to fetch the data. I tried print_r() as well, it displayed an empty MongoCursor object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract row from the cursor first:

```
$cursor = $tracking->sessions->find(array("fb_id"=> $document["fb_id"]),array("ts"=>1))->sort(array("ts"=>-1))->limit(1);
print_r($cursor->getNext());
```